# Ni en tus sueños

Tags: traducción

Is there another alternative for 'get real'? I'd like to say it in this context:

> A: ¿Eres mi nena?
>
> B: ¡Ni en tus sueños!

Comment: "Ni en pintura" es algo que podría decir.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternatives with *soñar*:

- ¡Sueñas!

Alternatives without *soñar*:

- ¡Oh por favor, se realista!
- ¡Pon los pies en la tierra!
- ¡Ubicate chavo!
- ¡Ya estas peludo!
- ¡Alucinas tú hombre!
- ¡Estas loco!
- ¡Tas loco!
- ¡Ni madres!
- ¡Ni vergas!

Extremely humilliant and aggressive(can lead to violence):

- ¡No sería tu nena ni aunque fueras el último hombre en el mundo!
- ¡Prefiero que me parta un rayo a ser tu nena!

Comment: AFAIK "¡Ubicate chavo!", "¡Ya estas peludo!", "¡Ni madres!", "¡Ni vergas!" aren't used in all Spanish speaking regions. The last one is very rude in some countries.

Comment: Mexico City uses "Ubicate" a lot fyi.

Answer (score 7):

En caso de que la pregunta "¿Eres mi nena?" sea absurda, *B* puede contestar en efecto

> *¡Ni en tus sueños!*

Alternativas aún aludiendo a *soñar*:

- Ni soñando.
- Abre los ojos.
- Ni lo sueñes.
- Despierta.
- Ni en tu sueño más erótico (ligeramente agresivo).

Alternativas sin aludir a *soñar*:

- ¿Estás loco?
- Vuelve a la realidad.
- Ya madura. (pinpointing the not so mature character of the question)
- ¡Por favor! (long *o*)
- Ay no manches (*Méx.* eufemismo para *no mames*, lo cual es suficientemente vulgar para merecerlo)
- Ash/Ay, supéralo (*Méx.* teenage slang)